# Asterisk is treated differently in cp command in 12.04 and 16.04

Tags: bash

In order to make backups of configuration files in 12.04 I used the following syntax:

```
cp -p fstab *.bak
```

This worked without problem, file `fstab.bak` was created in the same folder with the same attributes as original file.
In 16.04 this command works absolutely differently. It creates `*.bak` file instead, i.e. the copy of the original file with the name asterisk-dot-bak. If some file with `bak` extension already exists in this folder, it does nothing and throws a warning:

> cp: target 'inputrc.bak' is not a directory

I assume globbing works differently in 12.04 and 16.04. I compared `shopt` output in both systems - the difference is slim and globbing options are the same. OR `cp` in 16.04 treats asterisk differently than it was in 12.04.
Is there a way to preserve the old behavior of `cp` command in 16.04?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the expected behavior cannot be reproduced to debug it properly.

Comment: It is your question. Why not just delete it that VTC?

Comment: @Pilot6 The question isn't high grade, but the answer is. :) What's VTC (my English isn't that good)?

Comment: VTC - vote to close

Comment: I read the answer. It explains everything very well. So keep the question.

Answer (score 25):

It's not a case of globbing going wrong, but which files are present in the directory:

1. No `.bak` file is present. Then `*.bak`, unless `nullglob` is set, expands to `*.bak`. So the command run is literally `cp -p fstab *.bak`.
2. Just `fstab.bak` is present. Then `*.bak` will expand to just `fstab.bak` and `cp -p fstab fstab.bak` is run. This is what you seem to expect regardless of the files present.
3. Multiple `*.bak` files are present (say, `fstab.bak` and `inputrc.bak`). So, `cp -p fstab fstab.bak inputrc.bak` is run. In that case, `cp` expects that the last argument be a directory, or that a target directory be specified using `-t`. If not, it will complain.

Don't do dumb things like `cp file *.bak`, whose results can vary based on the files present. Do you really want `fstab` to be backed up to `iputrc.bak` if `fstab.bak` wasn't present and `inputrc.bak` was?. If you're too lazy to type the filename, use brace expansion:

```
cp -p file{,.bak}
```

Better yet, use version control and [etckeeper](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/etckeeper.html) instead of the frail `.bak`-copying.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Actually in 12.04 the mentioned command always worked the same. It never expanded to `*.bak` as you mentioned in #1 and in case when any other `bak` file existed it never overwrited it as in your #3. In case `fstab.bak doesn't exist` it created the copy of `fstab` in `fstab.bak`, in case `fstab.bak exists` it overwrited it with a copy of `fstab`, so it was pretty predictable. But I see your point - better not rely on `*` behavior in the command line. I'm just curious - what has changed and who is responsible: bash, cp or something else.

Comment: @whtyger test with `bash --norc` in a new directory.

Comment: In 16.04 it works the same, but in 12.04 it creates `*.bak` file now. Should I compare `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc` in both systems? I compared them briefly, but haven't found nothing special.

Comment: @whtyger you said `shopt` output did not change, are you sure nullglob wasn't set?

Comment: nullglob is `off` in both systems.

Comment: Do `set -x` and the run `cp foo *.bak`. Is the bak file created and what output did you get from bash? Edit your question to add the output, please.

Comment: Sheesh! It stopped working in 12.04 also! I rebooted my PC and the mentioned `cp` command produces `*.bak` files on each attempt. So it may be not 12.04/16.04 issue. I'm sure that I was using it earlier, but I cannot debug it now, sorry. What can I do, mark this question as invalid?

Comment: @whtyger you can vote to close it as "could not be reproduced", it's one of the default reasons in the off-topic category.

Comment: Sorry for the disturbance. Your answer is good and right, that's my question which is faulty. I'll vote to close it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @whtyger: At the risk of repeating everything muru has said, for emphasis: `cp -p fstab *.bak` is a bad command. muru called it “dumb”; I would call it dangerous, in that it has high potential to do something other than what you want, possibly harmful. (As an example that muru didn’t mention, `cp passwd *.bak && cp group *.bak` could make a copy of your `passwd` file *called `*.bak`, **and then overwrite it*** with a copy of your `group ` file.) It was *never* working the way you thought it was. You *must* have *already* had an `fstab.bak` file before the first time `cp -p fstab *.bak` worked.

Comment: This topic is also addressed in [bash/shell pathname expansion for mkdir, touch etc?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/150916/80216#150992), [ls with directory path shows files, but ls with file pattern does not?](//superuser.com/q/893761/354511#893771), and [Who deals with the star `*` in `echo *`](//superuser.com/q/901183/354511).  Indirectly relevant (but very valuable background reading): [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/80216).

Comment: @muru: You could add a paragraph **2b**: If `fstab.bak` exists and is a directory, then `cp -p fstab *.bak` will copy `fstab` to `fstab.bak/fstab`.